# In-app purchase integration in phonegap build ios app

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap-build

I am integrating in-app purchase with my ios phonegap build method. I referenced https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase. It seems works.But my code stuck due to improper declaration. What i should define at

```
 var IAP = {
        list: [ 'inapptest' ],
        products:{id: 'testinapp',
            duration: 0}
    };
```

inapptest-is my in-app id
testinapp- is my SKU of app

It shows Error:could not load inapptest

If i am not giving product section as products:{} it shows same message.
Can someone help me please.
Is this things should filled with some other parameters.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out mistake i have done.
It must be 
`var IAP = {
        list: [ 'inapptest' ],
        products:{ }
    };`
And the 'inapptest' must be an approved product id.